# What is the purpose of the ^ operator?

Tags: c++, operators, xor

What is the `^` operator used for? It's not for the power function:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int x, y;

    cout << (x^y) << endl; /* this is the unkown (X^Y)*/

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's the xor. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/xor

Comment: and what does that mean?

Comment: when I cin 6 and 12 it cout 10

Comment: FYI, the behaviour of your program is undefined. So really in your example `cout<<(x^y)<<endl;` means "give me a bunch of nonsense" in the same way `cout<<std::pow(x^y)<<endl;` would.

Comment: I like to think of `A^B` as "flip every bit in A that is set to 1 in B". Easy to remember and it's also the most practical use case.

Comment: So you used search engines and found ... nothing?

Comment: yes, I only found "the xor" but i could't understand it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `^` operator is the bitwise `XOR`. Take for example 6 and 12

6 in binary is: `110`

12 in binary is: `1100`

The xor follows this rule: "**The first or the second but not both**". What does it mean? Its truth table should make it clear:

```
A     B     A^B
0     0      0
0     1      1
1     0      1
1     1      0
```

You can see that the only `1`-bits are those where or A or B (but not both) are set.

Back to the first example:

```
A    1100 => 12
B    0110 => 6
A^B  1010 => 10
```

Answer (score 2):

It's XOR. If you want more information about it see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or

Answer (score 2):

Power function in c++ is

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int x, y;
    std::cout << "Give numbers " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "x = ";
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << "y = ";
    std::cin >> y;
    std::cout << "Result = " << pow(x, y) << std::endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Your version is XOR (logical operation) which is used to for example embedded systems etc.